# Why can't I GROUP BY 1 when it's OK to ORDER BY 1?

Tags: sql

Why are column ordinals legal for `ORDER BY` but not for `GROUP BY`? That is, can anyone tell me why this query

```
SELECT OrgUnitID, COUNT(*) FROM Employee AS e GROUP BY OrgUnitID
```

cannot be written as

```
SELECT OrgUnitID, COUNT(*) FROM Employee AS e GROUP BY 1
```

When it's perfectly legal to write a query like

```
SELECT OrgUnitID FROM Employee AS e ORDER BY 1
```

?

I'm really wondering if there's something subtle about the relational calculus, or something, that would prevent the grouping from working right.

The thing is, my example is pretty trivial. It's common that the column that I want to group by is actually a calculation, and having to repeat the exact same calculation in the GROUP BY is (a) annoying and (b) makes errors during maintenance much more likely. Here's a simple example:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,LastSeenOn), COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee AS e
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,LastSeenOn)
```

I would think that SQL's rule of normalize to only represent *data* once in the database ought to extend to code as well. I'd want to only right that calculation expression once (in the `SELECT` column list), and be able to refer to it by ordinal in the `GROUP BY`.

Clarification: I'm specifically working on SQL Server 2008, but I wonder about an overall answer nonetheless.

Comment: what SQL are you using? (it's Standard Query Language, not not so standard after all....)

Comment: coding `ORDER BY n` is harder to maintain than `ORDER BY YourColumn` because someone will come in and add a column to the query and alter the sorting without even noticing.  I equate `SELECT *` and `ORDER BY n` as acceptable for quick development work but completely unacceptable for production queries

Comment: @KM - That's certainly a valid perspective (one of my coworkers said the same thing), but I think it's a matter of balancing the evils. In at least some cases, the complexity of the expression that must be restated seems to make it the greater evil. Plus, I still want to know *why*.

Comment: @Yanick: It's **Structured** Query Language, not Standard Query Language. (You're right about it not being so standard, though...)

Answer (score 8):

One of the reasons is because ORDER BY is the last thing that runs in a SQL Query, here is the order of operations

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

so once you have the columns from the SELECT clause you can use ordinal positioning

EDIT, added this based on the comment
Take this for example

```
create table test (a int, b int)
insert test values(1,2)
go
```

The query below will parse without a problem, it won't run

```
select a as b, b as a
     from test
    order by 6
```

here is the error

Msg 108, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The ORDER BY position number 6 is out of range of the number of items in the select list.

This also parses fine

```
select a as b, b as a
     from test
    group by 1
```

But it blows up with this error

Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: But what you're saying relates to the actual *execution* of the query. As far as I can see, an ordinal could be resolved by the interpreter at the time it parses the query, before anything has actually been executed.

Comment: I don't think that your example is correct. The code is syntactically correct, so technically speaking, it does go through the parsing stage successfully. I don't know how to check this, but I'm willing to bet that in both of your error examples, the query never actually executes as such -- no data or index pages are examined. The query optimizer can trivially see that the ORDER example does not have 6 columns. The GROUP example will fail even sooner than that, since the query is illegal given the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of elementary inconsistencies in SQL, and use of scalars is one of them. For example, anyone might expect

```
    select * from countries
    order by 1
```

and

```
    select * from countries
    order by 1.00001
```

to be a similar queries (the difference between the two can be made infinitesimally small, after all), which are not.

Answer (score 1):

use aliasses :

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,LastSeenOn) as 'seen_year', COUNT(*) as 'count'
    FROM Employee AS e
    GROUP BY 'seen_year'
```

** **EDIT** **

if `GROUP BY alias` is not allowed for you, here's a solution / workaround:

```
SELECT seen_year
     , COUNT(*) AS Total 
  FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,LastSeenOn) as seen_year, *
    FROM Employee AS e
  ) AS inline_view
GROUP 
    BY seen_year
```

Comment: doesn't work in SQL Server.... Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Your edit would certainly work. As I'm in SQL Server 2008, I'd probably write it in a CTE to be cleaner. There's no doubt that there's a way around the problem. I'm really hoping to expand my understanding of SQL by seeing if there's a real reason for the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the standard specifies if it is valid, but I believe it is implementation-dependent.  I just tried your first example with one SQL engine, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

databases that don't support this basically are choosing not to. understand the order of the processing of the various steps, but it is very easy (as many databases have shown) to parse the sql, understand it, and apply the translation for you. Where its really a pain is when a column is a long case statement. having to repeat that in the group by clause is super annoying. yes, you can do the nested query work around as someone demonstrated above, but at this point it is just lack of care about your users to not support group by column numbers.