# Reducing lines and readability in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables namely:

list_a:

```
 ID  Date  pg

23  2016-11-30  sub
23  2016-12-03  sub
23  2016-12-04  sub
23  2016-12-05  sub
69  2017-07-21  Closed
69  2017-07-22  Closed
69  2017-07-23  Closed
92  2016-11-29  sub
92  2016-11-30  sub
46  2017-01-11  In
46  2017-01-12  In
46  2017-01-13  In
```

list_b:

```
ID  Name

23  B
46  B
69  X
92  B
```

**My task is to write an sql query such that I get count of each date with name 'B' and the count should be greater than 4.**

So far I have written the following query which gives me the output:

```
SELECT date, count(Name) as CountName FROM
(
SELECT list_b.ID as Id,list_b.Name as Name,Date from list_b
inner JOIN list_a
on list_b.ID=list_a.ID
) t
where Name='B'
group by Date
Having count(Name)>4
order by count(Name) desc;
```

I am trying to make my **query more readable and less chunkier**.
Is there a better way that you can suggest to solve this problem?

**Note: the above tables are snippets of the original tables!**

Comment: Your query will produce empty result on your data.

Comment: @PHPNinja No, OP does not need to enumerate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spare subquery that isn't necessary. Also a personal preference to use an alias rather than table names (on a table called t_databaseassociation this does make a big difference)

Try

```
SELECT date, count(name) as countname 
 from list_b b
  inner JOIN list_a a on b.ID= a.ID
 where Name='B'
  group by Date
   Having count(Name)>4
    order by count(Name) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't use CTE `with` clause in mysql, but you can create temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t AS (
    SELECT list_b.ID AS Id,list_b.Name AS Name,Date
   FROM list_b
   INNER JOIN list_a ON list_b.ID=list_a.ID
);

SELECT date, count(Name) AS CountName
FROM t
WHERE Name='B'
GROUP BY Date HAVING count(Name)>4
ORDER BY count(Name) DESC;
```

Comment: Temporary table is excess.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Date`, COUNT(Name) as CountName
FROM list_a
NATURAL JOIN list_b
WHERE Name = 'B'
GROUP BY `Date`
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 4
ORDER BY CountName DESC;
```

Comment: `natural join` is an abomination because it does not take properly declared foreign key references into account.  I would strongly advise you not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    list_b.Date AS date,
    count(Name) AS CountName
FROM list_b
INNER JOIN list_a ON list_b.ID=list_a.ID
WHERE list_b.Name = 'B'
GROUP BY list_b.Date HAVING count(list_b.Name) > 4
ORDER BY count(Name) DESC
```

Comment: I edited my answer, you are quite right group by 1 will not work in sql-server. refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630998/8872639

Comment: @LJ01 *Is group by 1 valid???* Yes, the positional number of a field in output may be used instead of the name/expression in GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: this is valid in sql-server?  my bad

Comment: I wasn't exactly intending to argue it wasn't valid, just a new trick for me... I'll try it when I'm next in front of a pc

Comment: @Akina . . . The use of positional field numbers is part of the standard for `ORDER BY` (although  think it is deprecated).  It is NOT standard SQL for `GROUP BY` (and column aliases are not supported either).  Some databases extend SQL to allow them.